# animation on alert box

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a alert box and would like to apply below animation when it "appears":

```
Scale From 0.94 to 1.0
Opacity From 0 to 1
Time 0.50ms
x1: 0.48, y1: 0.44, x2: 0.01, y2: 1.2
```

Can someone guide on how to achieve this in swift ?

Code:

```
self.view.alpha = 0    
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05,
                animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.alpha = 1.0
                },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.48, y: 0.44)
self.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.94, 0.94, 1)
self.view.alpha = 0




 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                  self.view.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                  self.view.alpha = 1.0
                  self.view.frame.origin =  CGPoint(x: 0.01, y: 1.2)
                  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
```

Comment: Thanks David Yang Liu. can you please explain why we need - self.view.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

Comment: your starting transform is CATransform3DMakeScale(0.94, 0.94, 1) you want to animate to CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1) which is basically CGAffineTransformIdentity they layer with out any transform on it

Comment: ok. only a small change. this line - self.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), x and y would be 0.01 and 1.2 ?

Comment: x1: 0.48, y1: 0.44, x2: 0.01, y2: 1.2 , this is what you wanted right ? so before the animation block we set the origin to x1: 0.48, y1: 0.44 and we animate to  CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) ahh i see yea its a typo suppose to animate to CGPoint(x: 0.01, y: 1.2) ill update